# RN - Using props within style declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'd like to use a prop value to add color dynamically - relevant to the parent view.

I have the following -

```
  <Text style={[copyStyles.copyrightTxt, copyStyles.copyColor{this.Props.Color}]}>&copy; Copyright 2019 LRM Security Ltd</Text>
```

which would be styled via:

```
const copyStyles = StyleSheet.create({

  copyColorOrange:{
    color:'#f79431',
  }
 });
```

But I get an error 'unexpected token' - can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong please?

Comment: Why don't you just set the colors as `orange` instead of what you have? It would be much easier

Comment: that is one of 3 styles dependant on bg color of a parent view - style color is passed in as prop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make dynamic styles in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363671/can-i-make-dynamic-styles-in-react-native)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access properties of objects in two ways:

```
objectName.propertyName
```

or you can use the alternative way that allows you to use strings

```
objectName["propertyName"]
```

You should use the alternative way to access the value inside the styles object by constructing the string that you need.

```
 copyStyles[`copyColor${this.props.Color}`]
```

also isn't `props` meant to be all lowercase?

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to nest your property:

```
const copyStyles = {   
copyColor:{
    Orange:{
        color:'#f79431',
    }
  }
 };
```

And use : copyStyles.copyColor[this.props.Color]