# Access to style property and change it

Tags: react-native

I am new to React-Native. Say I have a styleSheet contains style for a green button:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff', 
  },
  greenB:{
    padding: 5,
    height: 80,
    width: 80,  
    borderRadius:160,    
    backgroundColor:'green',    
  }, ........
```

And for some reason I need to change that colour in my code.

```
render(){
....
const {container, greenB}=styles; //Not sure, how else can I define greenB?

greenB.backgroundColor='black';

return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.greenB} >
          ....
```

How can I access backgroundColor from greenB and change that?
I'm getting a TypeError "Attempted to assign to readonly property",
which is reasonable cause styles is a const.
tried to read about state management but not sure how to use it in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make dynamic styles in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363671/can-i-make-dynamic-styles-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

React Native's *StyleSheet.create* is used for better performance and clean code, It caches the style ids to reduce the amount of data that goes through the bridge, so that is why you cannot alter it but only use it .

But there're many solutions, You can use simple javascript object and alter the values as you want.

For example:-

```
let Styles= {
            Text:{ 
                 color:'blue'
                 }
          }
Styles.Text.color= 'green'


<Text style={Styles.Text} > </Text>
```

More over, For dynamic styling i recommend using states instead of variables .