# How to dynamically change zIndex in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react native, how do I dynamically change the Zindex in react native? or how do I hide/show using some other dynamic way?

```
import { styles } from './App_styles';

 export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      
      <Pressable onPress={()=>{styles.popup.zIndex=0}}>
      <View style={styles.popup}>
        
      </View>
      </Pressable>

      <View style={styles.main_content}>

      </View>

    </View>
  );
  }
```

App_styles:

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    body:{
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        height:'100%',
    },

    popup: {
        position:'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)',
        height:'100%',
        width:'100%',
        zIndex:1,
        alignSelf:'center',
        marginTop:'30%',
    },
    
    main_content:{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width:'100%',
        height:'100%'

    },
    
});
```

I'm not sure how to dynamically change properties in react native using js

Comment: Please learn the basics first; they're the same for React and React Native: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make dynamic styles in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363671/can-i-make-dynamic-styles-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use state to update the style of the popup:

```
import { styles } from './App_styles';
import {useState} from 'React';

 export default function App() {

  const [zIndex, setZIndex] = useState(1);

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      
      <Pressable onPress={()=>{setZIndex(0)}}>
      <View style={[styles.popup, {zIndex: zIndex}]}>
        
      </View>
      </Pressable>

      <View style={styles.main_content}>

      </View>

    </View>
  );
  }
```

Comment: Just link them to the docs page instead, there's no need to post an answer here.

Comment: @ChrisG i think this answer is fine, and the answer isn't the same as stylesheet.create does not exist in react so many people may not realize you can style inline in an array

Comment: @ChrisG its a beginner question for sure

Comment: thank you so much, but I'm a little confused why can't we change the property of styles directly? like in my code I did `styles.popup.zIndex=0` I mean what's the use of javascript if you can't directly change the values like in css

Comment: @cakelover In React, if you want any UI update, you have to update the state to make it render again, checkout the basics of React first

Answer (score 1):

Just use useState hook

```
  import { styles } from './App_styles';

  export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

  return (
   <View style={styles.body}>
   {show && <View style={styles.popup}>
    
  </View>}
  
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setShow(!show)}>
  <Text>Show/Hide</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <View style={styles.main_content}>

  </View>

</View>
  );
 }
```